# How can I count visible-set elements inside a hidden div?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements inside a div. Some elements are hidden, some are not.

```
<div class="master">
  <div class="child">element 1</div>
  <div class="child" style="display:none">element 2</div>
  <div class="child">element 3</div>
  <div class="child">element 4</div>
</div>
```

I can count the visible elements by `$('.child:visible').length` (which would be 3 in this case)

But if the master div is invisible itself, I cannot count visible child elements anymore (as they also are invisible by their parent div)

```
<div class="master" style="display:none">
  <div class="child">element 1</div>
  <div class="child" style="display:none">element 2</div>
  <div class="child">element 3</div>
  <div class="child">element 4</div>
</div>
```

I get 0 visible elements. Is there any other way to count that elements, which are not set 'invisible' explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you could use the `:visible` selector for this, but as the parent is also hidden it won't work here.

The workaround you can use in this case is to use `filter()` on the children and determine which are *not* set to `display: none`:

```js
let count = $('.master .child').filter((i, el) => el.style.display !== 'none').length;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master" style="display: none">
  <div class="child">element 1</div>
  <div class="child" style="display: none">element 2</div>
  <div class="child">element 3</div>
  <div class="child">element 4</div>
</div>
```